# "AttributeError: 'MiniSom' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_"

Tags: python, data-science, geospatial

I'm trying to follow along with [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-geospatial-data-f0584f0b04ec) but when I get to the "Self Organizing Maps (SOMs)" section I run the code and get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'MiniSom' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'
```

It's pretty clear that MiniSom doesn't have the attribute 'cluster_centers_' unlike the Kmeans model which is referenced further above in the post, but my question is... what could be changed to make this code run as intended?

After some research it looks like MiniSom has a win_map attribute which I'm struggling to implement with my dataset.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the code snippet.

You must use `cluster_centers` instead of `model.cluster_centers_`

The correct snippet is:

```
## find real centroids
cluster_centers = np.array([vec for center in model.get_weights() 
                            for vec in center])
closest, distances = scipy.cluster.vq.vq(cluster_centers, 
                                         X_preprocessed)
```